# DDD NoSQL Storage and Domain Model vs. View Model

Tags: domain-driven-design, nosql

I'm trying to use DDD pattern and as a persistent storage I'm considering use of a NoSQL database like LiteDB, RavenDB or DocumentDB.

One of the advantages for me, over relational DB, would be my domain models (whole aggregates) could be serialized as a JSON document and stored in a DB avoiding domain model to data model mapping.

But what about reading the data for the purpose of displaying it on the screen. My UI is displaying views based on a view models, but how to construct them? Do I query the document DB via. my domain model and then map it to view model?

I'm asking this, because it's usually mentioned "don't use your domain model for queries (read model)".

Comment: In your application service use repository to retrieve aggregate from your NoSQL database and then use some different view model to pass it to frontend. Also consider getting some knowledge about CQRS if you're facing problems like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> One of the advantages for me, over relational DB, would be my domain models (whole aggregates) could be serialized as a JSON document and stored in a DB avoiding domain model to data model mapping.

Yup, that's good.

> But what about reading the data for the purpose of displaying it on the screen. My UI is displaying views based on a view models, but how to construct them? Do I query the document DB via. my domain model and then map it to view model?

Yes.  The interesting question is *when*.

You can do that work synchronously with the request.

You can do that work synchronously with the request, but cache the result, so that subsequent queries of the same view are faster.

You can do that work asynchronously -- using background processes to load views into the cache, so that all of the queries are quick.

The basic idea is that each time you write a change to the document, you signal the asynchronous process that a change has happened, and then the process loads the data that it needs to update the cached view.

The "cache" might be, for example, a document store that holds your most recently composed view model.

The cached view might also include meta data that allows to determine at the time of the request if you need to rebuild the view.  [RFC 7234](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234) is probably a good place to start when thinking about cache meta data.

As Pawel noted, separating the write model and the read model is the big theme of [cqrs](/questions/tagged/cqrs).  There's quiet a lot of literature available.  I'd suggest starting from [Martin Fowler's overview](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html).

Comment: My project is rather small, it has no backend and everything runs locally, but I still want to try to apply DDD on some parts. I feel like CQRS and async writes/reads would be an overkill. I would rather build my VMs in an app service, like Paweł mentioned. Currently my only concern is if I have an aggregate with several properties and child collections, but I want to retrieve just few properties for the purpose of displaying these data in a list, how would I do that? ... >>

Comment: ... >>  Fetching the whole aggregate and then building a VM with just 2 properties is complete waste. I feel like I should always write two versions of the document, one for the detail and the other for the list.

Answer (score 1):

It is important to understand that your domain model consists of both behaviour and state. The only thing you need to persist is state.

When you realise this, you will also figure out that an aggregate state is not something scary to run your queries on. But you definitely should not use your repositories to compose read/view models - simple queries would suffice. There it becomes handy to separate your domain objects state into simple DTOs (documents), which you will store in the database, and keep them as properties in your domain objects. This is a bit different than shown in the book but in practice it works well. You will at least stop worrying if you are encapsulating good enough and will not write serialisation and persistence tests. [This article](https://vaughnvernon.co/?p=879) mentions it under the *Domain Object Backed By a State Object* section.